# Unity GoogleVR How to get rid of the back button in the upper left corner?

Tags: virtual-reality

My version is 0.9.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDEIc.png)

Comment: Can you explain what do you understand by back button? I don't see anything like this in the screenshot.

Comment: Never mind I get what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know it isn't possible right now. I tried searching for it in sdk, but only thing I found was empty function. I tried removing it, but it didn't help as well. Hopefully they will add it in future updates.